# Need help identifying power transistor 11SL60H

Tags: transistors, switch-mode-power-supply, repair

Hopefully someone can help me identify what these two transistors are.  I believe they're toast as they are open across all pins.

[image]

Normally I can google parts like these but for this one I get absolutely nothing.  Not sure of the brand either.  It's on a Dell monitor switching power supply board by the way.  That's why I believe it's a power transistor of some sort.  They trace directly into a TEA1716T control IC if that helps.  Maybe someone can suggest a substitute.

Comment: TEA1716T helps – because there's an NXP [Application Note](http://www.nxp.com/documents/application_note/AN11179.pdf) explaining which MOSFETs go where. Based on the values of the components driving your MOSFET's **G**ate (see the little "G" on one pad?), you can deduct a gate charge \$Q_G\$. Based on comparing the size of the component with MOSFETs with similar gate charge, you might be able to find some whose voltage and current ratings make sense. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the help.  Most of the info in the application notes are over my head, sadly.  I know those are power mosfet's now and are definitely toast.  The board was blowing it's fuse before I unsolders the mosfet's legs.  I got this board broken and don't know what caused the failure.  Do you think the TEA1716T is ok or would you recommend replacing it along with the mosfet's.

Answer (score 2):

It is AP11SL60H, from APEC.
http://www.alldatasheet.com/ may help you in similar situations.

Comment: Thank you so much!  Looking around I couldn't source that exact part.  Do you think this is a suitable substitute?

http://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/datasheet/f7/7a/de/10/5c/f3/49/e4/DM00153162.pdf/files/DM00153162.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.DM00153162.pdf

Comment: This mosfet look closer to the original, but the capacitive characteristics are a little different. You could try, but I think it could be a good idea if you study the app note suggested by Marcus before the substitution.